# Apcupsd startup issues

Tags: power-management

I am having trouble getting `apcupsd` to start up properly.

When I put `</etc/init.d/apcupsd start>` in the GNOME startup application, apcupsd starts, but apcaccess status shows `COMMLOST` on the USB port. Yet, if I type in `<ps -ef |grep apc>`,  I find a PID.

After much trial and error - putting this entry in the GNOME application startup app works.

```
sudo /bin/systemctl start apcupsd
```

Now comm port shows `Status: ONLINE` Does anyone have an idea why one works and not the other?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with COMMLOST with a USB connection. After a lot of research, I found that with a USB connection you should change `DEVICE /dev/ttys0` to `DEVICE`. This forces apcupsd to search everywhere to find the UPS and connect correctly.

Comment: Excellent advice!